# how to trigger fancybox-thumbs gallery on anchor click

Tags: jquery, fancybox

Have any one tried to activate fancybox thumbnail gallery using a button or an anchor click, Currently one can use fancybox by clicking on the image which takes you to the popup image gallery, In my condition i want a simple button or an html anchor , so that when a user click on the button or anchor the modal popup gallery should be displayed. Also my images will be coming from db ,  Any ideas how to do this ???

Code from fancybox website which runs when clicking on an image

```
$('.fancybox-thumbs').fancybox({
            prevEffect: 'none',
            nextEffect: 'none',

            closeBtn: false,
            arrows: false,
            nextClick: true,

            helpers: {
                thumbs: {
                    width: 50,
                    height: 50
                }
            }
        });
```

Updated Working script:

```
 $('a.gallery').click(function () {
        $('.fancybox-thumb').click();
    });
```

Comment: You want to show the fancy gallery when a#gallery is clicked?

Comment: yes exactly thats what i m looking for

Comment: You're probably going about this wrong. Typically this is done by giving your anchor tag's href attribute the id of the div you want to overlay in your Fancybox.

Comment: any examples of how to acheive this type of functionality

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was thinking about this (since your earlier question) and maybe you could try simulating a click in the first element classed .fancybox-thumbs

```
$('#gallery').click(function(){
      $('.fancybox-thumbs:first').click();
});
```

Let me know

Comment: well nothing happens now , in d above script , d fancybox is not called

Comment: i am just editing the given sample to get the desired results before making it on the test website

Comment: maybe you could provide a http://jsfiddle.net with the essential for the question?

Comment: hey , i have updated the question with the working answer , thanks for your help , much appreciated:)

Comment: So it was working? did you have to do any change? anyway i am glad you got it working ;)

Answer (score 0):

you can do something like this: Define an array with the properties and the images

```
var galPhotos = [{
        href : '../img/galeria/fondo1.jpg','nextEffect' : 'none',   prevEffect    : 'none', closeBtn: false,  arrows: false, nextClick: true, helpers: { thumbs: { width: 50, height: 50  } },
        href : '../img/galeria/fondo2.jpg','nextEffect' : 'none',   prevEffect    : 'none', closeBtn: false,  arrows: false, nextClick: true, helpers: { thumbs: { width: 50, height: 50  } },
        href : '../img/galeria/fondo3.jpg','nextEffect' : 'none',   prevEffect    : 'none', closeBtn: false,  arrows: false, nextClick: true, helpers: { thumbs: { width: 50, height: 50  } },
        href : '../img/galeria/fondo4.jpg','nextEffect' : 'none',   prevEffect    : 'none', closeBtn: false,  arrows: false, nextClick: true, helpers: { thumbs: { width: 50, height: 50  } }];
```

and then, simply

```
$('a#gallery').live('click',function(){
     $.fancybox(galPhotos);
});
```

Didn't test it for your config but mine is (and works fine):

```
var galPhotos = [
                    {href : '../img/galeria/fondo1.jpg','nextEffect' : 'fade',   'prevEffect'    : 'fade'}, 
                    {href : '../img/galeria/fondo2.jpg','nextEffect' : 'fade',   'prevEffect'    : 'fade'},
                    {href : '../img/galeria/fondo3.jpg','nextEffect' : 'fade',   'prevEffect'    : 'fade'}, 
                    {href : '../img/galeria/fondo4.jpg','nextEffect' : 'fade',   'prevEffect'    : 'fade'},
                    {href : '../img/galeria/fondo5.jpg','nextEffect' : 'fade',   'prevEffect'    : 'fade'},
                    {href : '../img/galeria/fondo6.jpg','nextEffect' : 'fade',   'prevEffect'    : 'fade'} 
                ];
```

or simply simulate the click to the class

```
$('#gallery').click(function(){
      $('.fancybox-thumbs:first').click();
});
```

let me know how it went

Comment: but my images will be populated from db

Comment: its just displaying the first image , cant see thumbnails

Comment: Can you provide a testing link?

Comment: sorry , i am doing it locally , any ideas where i m getting it wrong ?? i have copied exactly ur suggested answer

Comment: answered you in the last question you maid

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this works:

```
<a class="fancybox-thumb" rel="fancybox-thumb" href="link_to_large_image.png" title="Image title">
<img src="link_to_small_image.png" alt="" />
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

For new visitors,

```
$('[data-fancybox="gallery"]').fancybox({
    thumbs : {
      autoStart: true,
      axis: 'x'
    }
  });
```